# Symfony2 get root directory path from command class

Tags: php, symfony

What is the way to get root directory path from command class in symfony 2 ? Note : Not from controller class as I am creating a CLI command.

Or is there a a way to define a path in config file and access in anywhere ?

Comment: Did you tried this $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir(); ?

Comment: It doesn't work in command class

Comment: Not with that exact syntax, but if you extend ContainerAwareCommand as in my answer below yes, you can.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By extending ContainerAwareCommand you can access the root directory path  using:

```
$this->getContainer()->get('kernel')->getRootDir()
```

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html#getting-services-from-the-service-container

Comment: it says Call to undefined method

Comment: How to access config.yml parameters from the same class ?

Comment: @MDeSilva `$this->getContainer()->getParameter('parameter_name')`